# Use Highcharts in Symfony 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony4

I need to use Highcharts graphs in Symfony 4, but I have a bug with jQuery dependency. In my `app.js`, I have this `import` and it works:

```
import '../js/highcharts'
import '../js/exporting'

//use $ in all project
let $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;
```

But my bug is in base.html.twig

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried to download this file and use with my project but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you use webpack encore bundle, you need to include your app.js file in your base file. When I see your error, jQuery seems not being included in your page

Did you uncomment ".autoProvidejQuery()" in your webpack.config.js ? And install it via NPM or Yarn ?

For webpack encore bundle : [Like mentioned here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html)

```
{# templates/base.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {# 'app' must match the first argument to addEntry() in webpack.config.js #}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}

            <!-- Renders a link tag (if your module requires any CSS)
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css"> -->
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->

        {% block javascripts %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}

        <!-- Renders app.js & a webpack runtime.js file
        <script src="/build/runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="/build/app.js"></script> -->
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i've already include this in my base.html.twig

    '{% block javascript %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
    {% endblock %}'

if I position it in bottom page he don't work but if is in a balise `<head>         {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
 </head>` it's work.

Answer (score 0):

i've already include this in my base.html.twig

```
{% block javascript %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

if I position it in bottom page he don't work but if is in a balise `<head>         {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
 </head>` it's work.